# Am I allowed to some how control a Google colaboratory session remotely

Tags: google-colaboratory

As per colaboratory Terms and conditions, Will Google block me if I some how managed to get a remote shell access to colaboratory session ?

Since colaboratory is basically a linux VM with internet access, there are many ways to do that.

I am asking this because, my project is bit complex and I need to make some live edit to few files while working on colaboratory

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about compliance with a third-party site's terms of service, rather than a programming question.

Comment: In the help menu of Google colab, there is a submenu called "Ask question on stackoverflow" . I didn't found any other way to ask this question. That is why I am asking it here.